# Discord.py Bot Doesn't Play Audio

Tags: python, discord

so I'm coding a discord music bot that essentially allows my bot to **play audio from youtube**. I can confirm to you that my code works and everything but for some reason, my bot just won't play audio. I've even installed `python -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]` but nothing has changed. Is there a setting that has to be toggled or an installation that has to be installed for it to be playing the audio or something else that I am excluding?
I'm not an expert at this so please explain to me what I am missing! (If you know).
Here's a snippet of my code:

```py
        html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search)
        video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode())
        await ctx.send("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_ids[0])

        song = pafy.new(video_ids[0])
        audio = song.getbestaudio()
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio(audio.url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS)

        voice_client.play(source) # This part doesn't work but no errors were encountered
```

Not sure why it's not working - again, please answer in the comments if you know why it's not playing!

Thanks,

SmartCoder

Comment: there's no errors though

Comment: Well, have you installed FFMPEG and gave the correct part to your installation?

Comment: Yes, I have. I've even restarted my laptop so that the changes can be executed but still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Okay, it worked when I deleted the **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS. I think I know why as it wasn't in proper format. But thanks for helping!